# Catch HDIV exception in Spring application

Tags: hdiv

I have a Spring 4 MVC application integrated with HDIV that works perfectly.

I have a requirement in my application if any HDIV error comes in the application then I have to send an email which will contain the HDIV error details. 
Is there any way in Spring MVC so that I can catch the HDIV error and send an email?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `org.hdiv.logs.Logger` extension to catch detected attacks and send the email.

To do it, you have to register your custom `Logger` in Hdiv configuration.
For example, in JavaConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableHdivWebSecurity
public class HdivSecurityConfig extends HdivWebSecurityConfigurationSupport {

    ...

    @Override
    public Logger securityLogger() {

        return new MyCustomLogger();
    }

}
```